# How can I compile a CUDA application that targets both Kepler and Maxwell Architectures?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I do development on desktops, which have a Titan X card (Maxwell architecture). However, the production code runs on servers which have K40 cards (Kepler architecture).

How can I build my code so that it runs optimally on both systems?

So far, I have used `compute_20,sm_20` but I think that this setting is not optimal.

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#gpu-compilation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you would want to do is build a *fat binary* that contains machine code (SASS) for `sm_35` (the architecture of the K40) and `sm_52` (the architecture of the Titan X), plus intermediate code (PTX) for `compute_52`, for JIT compilation on future GPUs. You do so via the `-gencode` switch of `nvcc`:

```
nvcc -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52
```

This ensures that the executable code generated is best suited to, and makes full use of, each of the specified architectures. When the CUDA driver or runtime loads a kernel when running with a specific GPU, it will automatically select the version with the matching machine code.

What building a fat binary does not do is adjust various parameters of your code, such as the launch configurations of kernels, to be optimal for the different architectures. So if you need to achieve the best possible performance on either platform you would want to profile the application and consider machine-specific source code adjustments based on the result of the profiling experiments.

Comment: I think you have duplicate flags `-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52`.

Comment: @Fabian Not duplicates: The first of those `-gencode` switches deposits `sm_52` SASS into the fat binary, the second deposits `sm_52` PTX into the fat binary, for JIT-compilation on future GPU architectures. You can check for yourself by using `cuobjdump --dump-sass` to extract the SASS versions from the fat binary, and `cuobjdump --dump-ptx` to extract the PTX versions.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

However, @njuffa's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32409047/3710632) is semantically correct, I'd like to point out some shorthand of nvcc's `-gencode` option. Precisely we can shorten:

```
-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=compute_52
```

into this:

```
-gencode arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\"
```

Which is described in Nvidia [doc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#extended-notation).